# .htaccess - need to replace "?" in URL with "&"

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, paypal

So, I have this url that unfortunately cannot be modified, and paypal checkout appends the token with "?token=.....". The problem is that the proxy url already contains several parameters, so the paypal token must be appended with "&token=.....", otherwise "token" is not visible as a query string var.

The only way think it might work is to replace the "?" with "&" in the .htaccess file. ( Unless someone has a better idea! )

**URL including paypal token:**
  `https://some.samplesite.com/proxy/091F126B7B6D624623606A1BB67EDC430885ABAF02AD5975FF2A8276E21FD083091F126B7B6D624623606A1BB67EDC430151C3DF14A66603F9389B45EC89C9057C76A20EA0B4746BA97D7027E67E9EBC6437DCCA31B42521A4794F8E766AB37A76C0E6BD4FC92C60351E7C5FADB37CF0F82210A04BF29A74/&trans=success?token=EC-8FJ83689WF858702D`

I need the .htaccess rule that would do the trick. I am also including the existing .htaccess file to make sure other rules do not get violated.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

# if not https, redirect
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

# if only / is present, need to stop looping (domain.com/)
RewriteRule ^$ - [L]

# match subdomain
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^app
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^\.]+)\.[^\.]+\.[^\.]+$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1?sub=%1 [QSA]

# ignore any .php|.html|.asp|.ico files and certain directories
RewriteRule ^(exec|images|css|js|xyz|(.*)\.php|(.*)\.html|(.*)\.asp|(.*)\.ico)($|/) - [L]

# stop if index.php
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# map all requests to 'path'
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?path=$1 [L]
```

Thanks for the help!

**Edited:**
Ultimately the string will be broken into following query string params

```
*path* - proxy/091F126B7B6D624623606A1BB67EDC430885ABAF02AD5975FF2A8276E21FD083091F126B7B6D624623606A1BB67EDC430151C3DF14A66603F9389B45EC89C9057C76A20EA0B4746BA97D7027E67E9EBC6437DCCA31B42521A4794F8E766AB37A76C0E6BD4FC92C60351E7C5FADB37CF0F82210A04BF29A74/

*sub* - some

*trans* - success
```

**Please note** *trans* is actually a part of *path*, but b/c it was appended using "&", it is converted into a query string param.

**htaccess log**

```
init rewrite engine with /proxy/091F126B7B6D624623606A1BB67EDC430885ABAF02AD5975FF2A8276E21FD083091F126B7B6D624623606A1BB67EDC430151C3DF14A66603F9389B45EC89C9057C76A20EA0B4746BA97D7027E67E9EBC6437DCCA31B42521A4794F8E766AB37A76C0E6BD4FC92C60351E7C5FADB37CF0F82210A04BF29A74/&trans=success
strip matching prefix: /proxy/091F126B7B6D624623606A1BB67EDC430885ABAF02AD5975FF2A8276E21FD083091F126B7B6D624623606A1BB67EDC430151C3DF14A66603F9389B45EC89C9057C76A20EA0B4746BA97D7027E67E9EBC6437DCCA31B42521A4794F8E766AB37A76C0E6BD4FC92C60351E7C5FADB37CF0F82210A04BF29A74/&trans=success -> proxy/091F126B7B6D624623606A1BB67EDC430885ABAF02AD5975FF2A8276E21FD083091F126B7B6D624623606A1BB67EDC430151C3DF14A66603F9389B45EC89C9057C76A20EA0B4746BA97D7027E67E9EBC6437DCCA31B42521A4794F8E766AB37A76C0E6BD4FC92C60351E7C5FADB37CF0F82210A04BF29A74/&trans=success
applying pattern ^ to uri proxy/091F126B7B6D624623606A1BB67EDC430885ABAF02AD5975FF2A8276E21FD083091F126B7B6D624623606A1BB67EDC430151C3DF14A66603F9389B45EC89C9057C76A20EA0B4746BA97D7027E67E9EBC6437DCCA31B42521A4794F8E766AB37A76C0E6BD4FC92C60351E7C5FADB37CF0F82210A04BF29A74/&trans=success
RewriteCond: input='443' pattern='!^443$' => not-matched
strip matching prefix: /proxy/091F126B7B6D624623606A1BB67EDC430885ABAF02AD5975FF2A8276E21FD083091F126B7B6D624623606A1BB67EDC430151C3DF14A66603F9389B45EC89C9057C76A20EA0B4746BA97D7027E67E9EBC6437DCCA31B42521A4794F8E766AB37A76C0E6BD4FC92C60351E7C5FADB37CF0F82210A04BF29A74/&trans=success -> proxy/091F126B7B6D624623606A1BB67EDC430885ABAF02AD5975FF2A8276E21FD083091F126B7B6D624623606A1BB67EDC430151C3DF14A66603F9389B45EC89C9057C76A20EA0B4746BA97D7027E67E9EBC6437DCCA31B42521A4794F8E766AB37A76C0E6BD4FC92C60351E7C5FADB37CF0F82210A04BF29A74/&trans=success
applying pattern ^ to uri proxy/091F126B7B6D624623606A1BB67EDC430885ABAF02AD5975FF2A8276E21FD083091F126B7B6D624623606A1BB67EDC430151C3DF14A66603F9389B45EC89C9057C76A20EA0B4746BA97D7027E67E9EBC6437DCCA31B42521A4794F8E766AB37A76C0E6BD4FC92C60351E7C5FADB37CF0F82210A04BF29A74/&trans=success
RewriteCond: input='GET /proxy/091F126B7B6D624623606A1BB67EDC430885ABAF02AD5975FF2A8276E21FD083091F126B7B6D624623606A1BB67EDC430151C3DF14A66603F9389B45EC89C9057C76A20EA0B4746BA97D7027E67E9EBC6437DCCA31B42521A4794F8E766AB37A76C0E6BD4FC92C60351E7C5FADB37CF0F82210A04BF29A74/&trans=success HTTP/1.1' pattern='\s/+(.+?)\?(token=[^&\s]+\S*)\s' => not-matched
strip matching prefix: /proxy/091F126B7B6D624623606A1BB67EDC430885ABAF02AD5975FF2A8276E21FD083091F126B7B6D624623606A1BB67EDC430151C3DF14A66603F9389B45EC89C9057C76A20EA0B4746BA97D7027E67E9EBC6437DCCA31B42521A4794F8E766AB37A76C0E6BD4FC92C60351E7C5FADB37CF0F82210A04BF29A74/&trans=success -> proxy/091F126B7B6D624623606A1BB67EDC430885ABAF02AD5975FF2A8276E21FD083091F126B7B6D624623606A1BB67EDC430151C3DF14A66603F9389B45EC89C9057C76A20EA0B4746BA97D7027E67E9EBC6437DCCA31B42521A4794F8E766AB37A76C0E6BD4FC92C60351E7C5FADB37CF0F82210A04BF29A74/&trans=success
applying pattern ^$ to uri proxy/091F126B7B6D624623606A1BB67EDC430885ABAF02AD5975FF2A8276E21FD083091F126B7B6D624623606A1BB67EDC430151C3DF14A66603F9389B45EC89C9057C76A20EA0B4746BA97D7027E67E9EBC6437DCCA31B42521A4794F8E766AB37A76C0E6BD4FC92C60351E7C5FADB37CF0F82210A04BF29A74/&trans=success
strip matching prefix: /proxy/091F126B7B6D624623606A1BB67EDC430885ABAF02AD5975FF2A8276E21FD083091F126B7B6D624623606A1BB67EDC430151C3DF14A66603F9389B45EC89C9057C76A20EA0B4746BA97D7027E67E9EBC6437DCCA31B42521A4794F8E766AB37A76C0E6BD4FC92C60351E7C5FADB37CF0F82210A04BF29A74/&trans=success -> proxy/091F126B7B6D624623606A1BB67EDC430885ABAF02AD5975FF2A8276E21FD083091F126B7B6D624623606A1BB67EDC430151C3DF14A66603F9389B45EC89C9057C76A20EA0B4746BA97D7027E67E9EBC6437DCCA31B42521A4794F8E766AB37A76C0E6BD4FC92C60351E7C5FADB37CF0F82210A04BF29A74/&trans=success
applying pattern ^(.*)$ to uri proxy/091F126B7B6D624623606A1BB67EDC430885ABAF02AD5975FF2A8276E21FD083091F126B7B6D624623606A1BB67EDC430151C3DF14A66603F9389B45EC89C9057C76A20EA0B4746BA97D7027E67E9EBC6437DCCA31B42521A4794F8E766AB37A76C0E6BD4FC92C60351E7C5FADB37CF0F82210A04BF29A74/&trans=success
RewriteCond: input='' pattern='^$' => matched
RewriteCond: input='demo.samplesite.com' pattern='!^app' => matched
RewriteCond: input='demo.samplesite.com' pattern='^([^\.]+)\.[^\.]+\.[^\.]+$' => matched
Rewrite URL to >> /proxy/091F126B7B6D624623606A1BB67EDC430885ABAF02AD5975FF2A8276E21FD083091F126B7B6D624623606A1BB67EDC430151C3DF14A66603F9389B45EC89C9057C76A20EA0B4746BA97D7027E67E9EBC6437DCCA31B42521A4794F8E766AB37A76C0E6BD4FC92C60351E7C5FADB37CF0F82210A04BF29A74/&trans=success?sub=demo&token=EC-76D265115N209873K [REWRITE]
```

Comment: Try adding your own dummy querystring e.g. `http://mydomain/return_url/?foo=bar` and see if Paypal does the appending of their token correctly `&token=...` . It does for things like `return_url` - I'm just not sure about what you are calling "checkout")

Comment: The query string that i mentioned is the one returned back from Paypal. The "returnURL" is the same just without "?token". Also in their docs they are saying this <<PayPal also appends this token as a GET parameter named token to your RETURN URL when redirecting the buyer back to your website from paypal.com.>>

Comment: In  that case, then do try, because in _most_ cases, merchants usually append their own "session"/custom value  - e.g. `http://domain/?sessionid=....` and Paypal correctly appends token to it `http://domain/?sessionid=123&token=456` . This way you hopefully don't have to muck with global stuff...Hth.

Comment: Maybe I was not very clear.... :-) Paypal is not appending it correctly, and thus I have to find a way to read the token. ( unless I am doing something wrong which i don't think I am )

Comment: With a "dummy query string"? In other words send your return url _already_  with some query string....`/?foo=bar`

Comment: I understand, but if you take a look at my .htaccess file, you will see that the URL string gets converted to /index.php?path=.... which unfortunately does not allow for a second "?" ... hope that makes sense

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have it this way:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

# if not https, redirect
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=302]

# convert ?token=... to &token=...
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(.+?)\?(token=[^&\s]+\S*)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1&%2? [L,NE,R=302]

# if only / is present, need to stop looping (domain.com/)
RewriteRule ^(index\.php)?$ - [L,NC]

# match subdomain
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^app
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+)\.[^.]+\.[^.]+$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1?sub=%1 [L,QSA]

# ignore any .php|.html|.asp|.ico files and certain directories
RewriteRule ^(exec|images|css|js|xyz|(.*)\.php|(.*)\.html|(.*)\.asp|(.*)\.ico)($|/) - [L]

# map all requests to 'path'
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?path=$1 [L,QSA]
```

---

**Update:**

While testing this with URL:

```
http://abc.dev.localhost/proxy/foobar/&trans=success?token=EC-8FJ83689WF858702D
```

It redirects to:

```
http://abc.dev.localhost/proxy/foobar/&trans=success&token=EC-8FJ83689WF858702D
```

And displays this for `print_r($_GET)` output:

```
Array
(
    [path] => proxy/foobar/
    [trans] => success
    [token] => EC-8FJ83689WF858702D
    [sub] => abc
)
```

Comment: Now I am getting this error in the logs: [2015-07-14 13:29:05.367] [1.114] (warn) [/proxy/091F126B7B6D624623606A1BB67EDC430885ABAF02AD5975FF2A8276E21FD083091F126B7B6D624623606A1BB67EDC430151C3DF14A66603F9389B45EC89C9057C76A20EA0B4746BA97D7027E67E9EBC6437DCCA31B42521A4794F8E766AB37A76C0E6BD4FC92C60351E7C5FADB37CF0F82210A04BF29A74/&trans=success] The specified path, file name, or both are too long. The fully qualified file name must be less than 260 characters, and the directory name must be less than 248 characters.

Comment: Please take a look at my updated question. The above log entry is actually just a warning. But the code you provided tries to go to the "proxy" directory... and that is not supposed to happen.

Comment: The reason being for the error is b/c you modified this line "RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1?sub=%1 [QSA]
" by adding [L,QSA]. Please note that the final rule in the file must be run.

Comment: Please take a look at the htaccess log file above. The last line should have been written as /index.php?path=/proxy/(...)

Comment: Yes, that is correct. The original URL does not have any "?" in it.

Comment: Please note that after the rules are applied, it is supposed to go to /index.php not /proxy

Comment: Is it possible that your server is setup to send everything to index.php by default? On my server I am still being sent to /proxy.

Comment: ok, i have made a minor modification to the code and it worked. I modified RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1?sub=%1 [QSA] ... i took out "L". However, now when i just go to the URL without any params ( https://demo.samplesite.com/ ) I am missing the "sub" param that is always supposed to yield "demo"

Comment: Maybe its a catch 22, but as soon as I add "L" I get the directory not found error. I think the reason is that when "sub" is obtained, the system is not supposed to stop.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83254/discussion-between-anubhava-and-artknight).

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this right before the `# if only / is present, need to stop looping (domain.com/)` comment:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)\?token=(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1?%1&token=%2 [L,R,NE]
```

Comment: nothing happens, the token param is still not available in query string